# ASP.NET MVC IIS Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have following 2 ASP.NET MVC Web Application under 1 VS Solution

1. Public Site
2. Admin Site

I don't want to deploy this as two separate IIS instance, my aim is to achieve the following

1. When user navigate to www.mysite.com it should go to the public site
2. When user navigate to www.mysite.com/admin it should go to the admin site.

How can this be achived

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Area's for separation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx) and deploy it as one app.